# ExportAsFixedFormat takes very long time

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to save many **pdfs** but the process of saving via `ExportAsFixedFomat` takes very long

Do you guys have some idea how to improve my Code (other functions,...)

**Code**

```
WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=wholeString, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
```

Comment: If the documents include a lot of detail or graphics (or on an older computer) they'll take longer to export.  For troubleshooting purposes, I'd suggest you try exporting several of the same files without VBA (File → Export → PDF). If they take a long time that way too then you will know VBA has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Tough to figure out the exact reason in your case. But you can try to deactivate the [screen updating](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating) like so:

```
..
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=wholeString, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
..
```

Comment: Honestly I'd be surprised if this made any noticeable difference (I haven't exported a lot of PDF's but how many times could it possibly be updating the screen per file?) ...but I could be wrong and I'm curious what the OP says.

Comment: @ashleedawg agree. But worth a shot, really depends on how many is "many"

Answer (score 0):

Excel recalculates the workbook before each PDF is generated.  Why this should be the case is not immediately obvious. The solution was to insert the following line of code at the beginning of the routine and turn it back to automatic at the end:

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

This reduces the total time.